# django unittest: Can't do subqueries with queries on different DBs

Tags: django

I am running unittest on Django v1.6.2 and received this error:

```
ValueError: Can't do subqueries with queries on different DBs.
```

However not happening when running the site.

I only have one database specified.

Did a quick search on google only one relevant result found and that didn't help me.

**UPDATE more details:**

This is an intermediate model to manage M2M relationships, and this is the query causing the problem:

```
ProductCategory.objects.filter(category=category, product=product).delete()
```

UPDATE: added trace

```
======================================================================
ERROR [0.079s]: test_sync (goproducts.apps.products.tests.productSyncTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/goproducts/goproducts/apps/products/tests.py", line 55, in test_sync
    product.objects.sync(self.message)
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/goproducts/goproducts/apps/products/managers.py", line 97, in sync
    ProductCategory.objects.filter(category=category, product=product).delete()
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 464, in delete
    collector.collect(del_query)
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 166, in collect
    reverse_dependency=reverse_dependency)
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 77, in add
    if not objs:
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 100, in __nonzero__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 709, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 772, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 94, in as_sql
    having, h_params = self.query.having.as_sql(qn=qn, connection=self.connection)
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 103, in as_sql
    sql, params = child.as_sql(qn=qn, connection=connection)
  File "/private/var/www/goproducts/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 401, in as_sql
    raise ValueError("Can't do subqueries with queries on different DBs.")
ValueError: Can't do subqueries with queries on different DBs.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you add in more details? Query and models

Comment: Ok will need to to know what is category and product? Under the hood they are converted to pk, so make sure that category and product are IDs. And also update the trace back,  along with the full view function may be!!!!

Comment: I believe the information I have provided is enough, the statement which caused the error is not a subquery.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the problem, I was using mock library to mock the sync function

```
    Category.objects.sync = MagicMock()
```

commented this out fixed it.

PS, I have made sure my test is not broken because I removed the mock.

Comment: So now you've broken a test somewhere. This is more a way to ignore a problem than to fix it.

Comment: Surely, when I removed that line, I would have used another approach to make sure the test is on purpose, thank you very much for your concern.

Comment: Your answer nor your question reflect that. Still, good to know ;)